# Is it possible to dual boot without boot screen?

Tags: boot, mac, graphics-card, linux-mint

Recently, I removed MacOS from MacPro (2010) and installed Windows 7 and Linux Mint on it. Then, my graphics card malfunctioned and I was forced to replace it.
The problem is my new card (GeForce 8800 GT) doesn't support Apple Boot Screen, so I can't choose between my two operating systems during startup.

Is there any way to choose a partition to boot from, without flashing EFI into graphics card or installing operating systems on two separate drives and removing one of them?

Comment: Can you use a pen drive or serial console?

Comment: On the regular macOS pre-boot screen you can navigate with arrow keys & Enter [or Ctrl Enter to set as 'permanent'] idk how that will work if you have removed macOS entirely.

Comment: set grub2 as default